# Adding "Delayed Charge" to Customer via QBO API v3

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

In QB Online we have the ability to add a "Delayed Charge" to a customer, and then assign selected charges to an invoice later. But I can't find anything in the API doc that tells me how to insert these charges programmatically. Am I missing something, or is it just not there yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This delayed charge when assigned to an Invoice from UI comes up as StatementCharge in Invoice Linked Txn if you query the API explorer.

This entity- StatementCharge is not yet supported by our service.

Comment: Any updates?  I'm looking to add a "Delayed Charge" programmatically as well.

Comment: This isn't in plan in near future for V3. Our V4 services are in progress and may take this up but not anytime soon.